# How to debug missing path in nvidia-docker build

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I am creating a nvidia-docker image with the following included in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -so /miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh  && chmod +x /miniconda.sh  && /miniconda.sh -b -p /miniconda  && rm /miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:$PATH
#this is stored in cache ---> fa383a2e1344
# check path
RUN /miniconda/bin/conda
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /miniconda/bin/conda: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c /miniconda/bin/conda' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

When I test the path using:

```
nvidia-docker run --rm fa383a2e1344 ls
```

then /miniconda does not exist hence the error.

I then altered the Dockerfile to replace /miniconda with a env var path ie:

```
ENV CONDA_DIR $HOME/miniconda
# Install Miniconda
RUN curl -so /miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x /miniconda.sh \
 && /miniconda.sh -b -p CONDA_DIR \
 && rm /miniconda.sh

ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR:$PATH

# check path
RUN $CONDA_DIR/conda
```

And get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /miniconda/conda: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c $CONDA_DIR/conda' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by setting the path to current dir rather than hitting `/`

```
   WORKDIR /miniconda
   RUN curl -so ./miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && chmod +x ./miniconda.sh \
    && ./miniconda.sh -b -p CONDA_DIR
```

Here is the build result for reference

```
  docker build - < Dockerfile 
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
  Step 1/5 : FROM node:12.16.0-alpine
   ---> 466593119d17
  Step 2/5 : RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl
   ---> Using cache
   ---> 1d6830c38dfa
  Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /miniconda
   ---> Using cache
   ---> 8ee9890a7109
  Step 4/5 : WORKDIR /miniconda
   ---> Running in 63238c179aea
  Removing intermediate container 63238c179aea
   ---> 52f571393bf6
  Step 5/5 : RUN curl -so ./miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh       && chmod +x ./miniconda.sh       && ./miniconda.sh -b -p CONDA_DIR
   ---> Running in b59e945ad7a9
  Removing intermediate container b59e945ad7a9
   ---> 74ce06c9af66
  Successfully built 74ce06c9af66
```